# Convert image to PDF using iText library in Android : Issue with image clarity

Tags: android, itext

I have successfully converted an image to PDF with the iText library in the android device, Samsung Galaxy Tab. There is no issue in viewing the PDF in Galaxy Tab. But, when I send the generated file via. email and open in it HTC desire or my PC the image is very much enlarged. What could be the issue?

Would anyone please help?

Comment: I think the issue is with image size. Could anyone sugget how could I resize and save the image to sd card with dimensions of A4 size page, without affecting the image quality? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by resizing the image to be converted to pdf, keeping the aspect ratio. This new image was used to create the PDF.